# Define a Class instance and create its objects and cast with it

Tags: objective-c, casting, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I have an interesting question
What I am trying to do is to use object's class (AppDelegate in this case)
And then use this class object like the next Code.
But the compiler doesn't like it.

```
Class appDelegateClass=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].class;
appDelegateClass *delegate = (appDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

10x people!